# split string while keeping separators

Tags: go

any way I can split this string `x+5-3+x=6+x-2` while keeping the separators, I tried regex split on `[\+\-]` but this gives me, `x, 5, 3, ...` and I need `x, +5, -3, +x` using `(?=[-+])` as in Java doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [FindAllString](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString)

```
  regexp.MustCompile(`[-+\?=]?([0-9]|x)`).FindAllString("x+5-3+x=6+x-2", -1)
```